# How to manually make Gnome keyring unlock a private key on MATE?

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring

I wanted Gnome keyring to unlock a private key on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 (that is, to show the modal dialog).

However, I can't find any way to do it:

- I haven't Seahorse installed;
- `ssh-add` seems to work separately from Gnome keyring.

How can I do that? I wanted to trigger the dialog, without installing Seahorse or anything else.

Comment: The source code analysis shows that the message about keyring unlock is contained in [`gnome-keyring` source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-keyring/3.36.0-1/daemon/ssh-agent/gkd-ssh-agent-interaction.c/?hl=101#L101). So this dialog will popup automatically on SSH/SSHfs access requiring this SSH key. Did you changed the contents of `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`? What is the output of `ps auxw | grep gnome-keyring | grep -v grep`?

Comment: The problem is that I have a script that runs many ssh connections in parallel. If when executed, the key is not unlocked, the dialog will pop up several times. For this reason, I wanted to find a way to make Gnome keyring unlock that key (if required) before starting the parallel connections.